# Objective-C: Sort keys of NSDictionary based on dictionary entries

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

OK so I know that dictionaries can't be sorted. But, say I have `NSMutableArray *keys = [someDictionary allKeys];` Now, I want to sort those keys, based on the corresponding values in the dictionary (alphabetically). So if the dictionary contains `key=someString`, then I want to sort `keys` based on the strings they correspond to. I think its some application of `sortUsingComparator` but its a little out of my reach at this point.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
NSArray *keys = [someDictionary allKeys];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSString *first = [someDictionary objectForKey:a];
    NSString *second = [someDictionary objectForKey:b];
    return [first compare:second];
}];
```

Comment: neither `keys` nor `sortedKeys` are a mutable dictionary here, they're immutable.

Comment: ops you meant a mutable array? I just did copy&paste from the question ha

Comment: Its giving this error: 
WFMB.V2[21844:f803] -[NSDecimalNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6898010 .. any idea what that could be?

Comment: Worked when I changed it to objectForKey instead of valueForKey

Comment: oh I see. I fixed that to objectForKey. sorry I didn't actually test it but glad it worked :)

Answer (score 3):

```
NSDictionary *dict = // however you obtain the dictionary
NSMutableArray *sortedKeys = [NSMutableArray array];

NSArray *objs = [dict allValues];
NSArray *sortedObjs = [objs sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
for (NSString *s in sortedObjs)
    [sortedKeys addObjectsFromArray:[dict allKeysForObject:s]];
```

Now `sortedKey` will contain the keys sorted by their corresponding objects.

Comment: What if its not just key value. What if each key corresponds to a dictionary and I want to sort by the key "name" inside that dictionary? Sorry I should've mentioned that in the OP. THanks for the help!

Comment: It always *is* "just" key-value, because that's what NSDictionary is for. What you mean is non-scalar values -- in that case you'll need to make this a function and apply recursion.

Comment: This is not very clever from the performance point of view and will not return the right result for some cases.

Comment: @Sven And I've mentioned it when OP asked -- so I don't see the reason for your downvote. (Btw you're free to implement this in hand-tuned assembly if you worry about the performance...)

Comment: @H2CO3 for a dictionary which contains the same value multiple times this will also return those keys multiple times. So a dictionary like this `{ @"a": @"x", @"b": @"x" }`  your code would return `[ @"a", @"b", @"a", @"b" ]` which certainly is not wanted here. And since no-one said that there never will be duplicated values your answer is wrong. And btw, even hand-tuned assembly won't make a difference if your algorithm is O(n^2) which yours is.

Answer (score 3):

**Sort keys of NSDictionary based on dictionary *keys***

Abobe is for returning a sorted array with based on dictionary content, this is for returning an array **sorted by dictionary key**:

```
NSArray *keys = [theDictionary allKeys];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    return [a compare:b];
}];
NSMutableArray *sortedValues = [NSMutableArray new];
for(NSString *key in sortedKeys)
    [sortedValues addObject:[dictFilterValues objectForKey:key]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write it here cause I didn't find it anywhere: To get an alphanumeric sorted NSDictionary back from an NSDictionary based on the value - which in my case was neccessary - you can do the following:

```
//sort typeDict alphanumeric to show it in order of values
    NSArray *keys = [typeDict allKeys];

    NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        NSString *first = [typeDict objectForKey:a];
        NSString *second = [typeDict objectForKey:b];
        return [first compare:second];
    }];
    NSLog(@"sorted Array: %@", sortedKeys);

    NSMutableDictionary *sortedTypeDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < [typeDict count]; i++){
        NSString *val = [typeDict objectForKey:[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:counter]];
        NSString *thekey = [sortedKeys objectAtIndex:counter];
        [sortedTypeDict setObject:val forKey:thekey];
        counter++;
    }
    NSLog(@"\n\nsorted dict: %@", sortedTypeDict);
```

Not a big deal!

Answer (score 1):

If any value from the dictionary is null then use this code

```
NSArray *keys = [typeDict allKeys];   
NSSortDescriptor *sd = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sd]];
NSLog(@"SORT 1 %@",sortedKeys);

NSMutableDictionary *sortedTypeDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
int counter = 0;
for(int i=0; i < [typeDict count]; i++){
    id val = [typeDict objectForKey:[sortedKeys objectAtIndex:counter]];
    NSString *thekey = [sortedKeys objectAtIndex:counter];
    [sortedTypeDict setObject:val forKey:thekey];
    counter++;
}
NSLog(@"\n\nsorted dict: %@", sortedTypeDict);
```