# Sorting array of dictionary in alphabetic order

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sorting, arraylist, nssortdescriptor

I have an array of 3 objects. The objects are of type of dictionaries. Each dictionary has different keys. I want sort this array in alphabetic order.

My Array Structure is as below

```
MyListArray:({Return=something;},{Departure=something;},{Both=something;});
```

How can I sort this in alphabetic order?

Comment: you want output like :- `MyListArray:({Both=something;},
 {Departure=something;}, {Return=something;});` ???

Comment: Yes.Thats my expected output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective-C: Sort keys of NSDictionary based on dictionary entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554780/objective-c-sort-keys-of-nsdictionary-based-on-dictionary-entries)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11554919/7505395

Comment: Will each dictionary always have only one key/value pair? If not what should the result be?

Comment: Only one key value pair in each dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Use `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` and compare the keys in de comparator. The key is the first key in `allKeys` of the dictionary.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [myListArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSDictionary* _Nonnull obj1, NSDictionary* _Nonnull obj2) {
    if (obj1.count == 0) {
        if (obj2.count == 0)
            return NSOrderedSame;
        else
            return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    if (obj2.count == 0)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    NSString *key1 = obj1.allKeys[0];
    NSString *key2 = obj2.allKeys[0];
    return [key1 compare:key2];
}];
```